# How to make an apk file downloadable from a react js website

Tags: reactjs

I am having an apk file stored in a folder of my react js project src/asset/myapp.apk, I want to make it downloadable from my portfolio website. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your static files in `public/` folder.
Then simply retrieve it by addressing `"/path/to/file.apk"`
When using `src/` filename will be processed and changed relative to your webpack config which can vary each time you run a build which is not a good practice.

If you're using `create-react-app` read this documentation:
[Using the Public Folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)

Note: if you are using gatsby, please use static/ folder instead of public.

Answer (score 0):

the best method put apk in public folder and when you want to click to download use this

```
const handleClick = () => {
    const apkUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/apk.name";
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = apkUrl;
    link.download = "apk.name;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link); 
  };
```